# Zener diode with breakdown voltage of 12V. How to plot a graph of V vs I indicating all important points?

Tags: diodes, zener

[image]

I am bit confused with the question here, because as per my understanding if the breakdown voltage is 12V, then if they are connected in opposite directions there will be no current flow through the circuit.

Then how could I plot a graph of voltage vs current?

Comment: A zener diode conducts as a normal diode in the forward direction.

Comment: "There will be no curent flow" is almost never true for diodes, even in reverse. There will be "negligibly little" might work. Since you've got this assignment, and it already includes Zener diodes, I'm pretty optimistic you know the Shockley diode equation. Time to revisit that! If you have never heard of the Shockley diode equation, assume a simpler diode model. What happens if v = 13 V? What if v = -13 V? What if v = 0?

Comment: Also, I've literally never seen a Zener diode drawn like this. If this is not from your textbook but some random website: find a different source of exercises. This one is very likely low quality.